# Array with fast insertion/deletion

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I am looking for a data structure that stores an array of elements and supports these operations:

1. Accessing element at a given index
2. Adding or removing an element at a given index (and hence shifting the following elements)

Arrays do the first operation in O(1) but the second one takes O(n), while linked lists do the opposite. Is there a middle-ground data structure? Say, something that can do both operations in O(lg n) or O(n^epsilon) "worst-case" time?

Note that I am not asking for a balanced binary search tree. Here the keys (indices) are changed and shifted every time a new element is added/removed. For example, removing the smallest element decreases the indices for all other elements by 1.

Comment: Just a regular List

Comment: List is implemented as ArrayList and LinkedList, both of them do at least one of those operations in linear time.

Comment: This formulation is imprecise. Every balanced search-tree will support both within log n time. If you view the key's as index, you are done. (But it's not an array of elements which effects iteration not considered in your task; that's where your question starts to be imprecise)

Comment: @sascha The point is that there is no order over the elements. The only order is the one created implicitly by adding or removing them. I'll make it more precise.

Comment: Still way too broad. That's such a vague specification that it's hard to work with. You can still make a balanced search tree work. It won't change the indices of the following ones, but it does not matter as your access/iteration still behaves as if this would have happened. You only need to use some growing index as key for each insert and maybe keep a key-gap-counter. (You got a friend upvoting your comments? :-D)

Comment: @sascha I still don't see how this helps. I am not inserting only at the end. I might want to insert in the middle. Having keys with gaps doesn't work either. What if I want to insert more elements than the gap lets me do?

Comment: No sorry. It's often way too wasteful to work on such broad tasks. Everytime you explain something, the poster adds some more specification unknown before. That's why a good question is so important. Example: *For example, removing the smallest element decreases the indices for all other elements by 1* says you have to decrease at worst-case n elements. You are done. That's a lower bound. But if would just describe your usage pattern and what you really want to achieve, maybe the indices do not have to be modified .

Comment: A rope with single elements at the leaves instead of strings would do it

Comment: @harold
The rebalancing in a rope can take linear time.

https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ropeimpl.html

The worst-case cost of rebalancing is nonetheless linear in the string. However, the observed behavior is that rebalancing typically consumes a small fraction of the running time. Indeed, all natural ways of building a rope of length N by repeated concatenation require total time linear in N. It is possible, but nontrivial, to design concatenation sequences that violate this.

Comment: @harold: It's not about being in favor of it or not. The second operation I want to support, i.e. adding an element, will cause the rope "concat" operation and this might take linear time due to rebalancing. So a rope cannot do operation 2 above in worst-case logarithmic time. I agree that the rope is quite effective in practice but I am looking for worst-case guarantees.

Comment: @Aryana their bounds don't even apply since they balance for length, I'm not sure what the worst case actually is for single-element leafs

Comment: Just don't use their rebalancing algorithm, apply tree rotations as if it's an AVL tree

Comment: But don't tree rotations breach the rope conditions? For example every element is supposed to be stored in a leaf, but a rotation might  move it up in the tree. I am very hazy about this. How do you "compare" concatenation nodes? I think I'll need a notion of comparability for AVL rotations to make sense.

Comment: Only if leaves participate in rotations, which they aren't supposed to do in an AVL tree either - at least not in the interpretation of an AVL tree where it only ever stores data in its internal nodes and the leaves are just `nil`. But since no one ever draws those `nil` leaves, it then seems as though nodes with only leaves as children are themselves leaves, and to make matters worse sometimes that's how it's defined..

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 3):

There is 'AVL-Array', an STL-style container that
performs both operations in **O(log n)**.

It is built on top of an AVL-Tree, but it is still not
an associative container, but sequential. 
It supports index access `[]` with `vector` semantics.

Notice that AVL-Array does not implement a **search** tree,
but rather a sequential container that 
happens to come in tree form. Indexing, iteration, insertion
and deletion all do what you would 
expect a `vector` to do.

You can find it [here](http://avl-array.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a kind of balanced binary tree whose in-order traversal gives the array elements in order, i.e., the leftmost node stores `A[0]` and the rightmost node stores `A[n-1]`, where `n` is the number of elements in the array.

At each node we will store the total size `s` of the sub-tree rooted at that node (i.e. the total number of nodes), the value `v` of the array element stored at that node, the left child `l` of the node, and the right child `r` of the node.

You can retrieve the value of `A[i]` from such a tree as follows (for simplicity of exposition, no error conditions are checked):

```
int get_element(node *n, int i) {
  int ls = (n->l == NULL) ? 0 : (n->l)->s;

  if (i < ls) return get_element(n->l, i);
  else if (i == s) return n->v;
  else return get_element(n->r, i-(ls+1));
}
```

If the tree is balanced, this will take `O(log n)` time.  Inserting at an index or deleting at an index is similar to any balanced tree scheme, except that you are using the sub-tree sizes to navigate rather than the key value, which will also take `O(log n)`.   Balanced tree data structures generally use a "rotation" to restore balance, e.g., a right rotation:

```
   y o                  o x  
    / \                / \   
 x o   C     ==>      A   o y
  / \                    / \ 
 A   B                  B   C
```

We can maintain the size of the new subtree at node `y` as `size(B)+size(C)+1`, and then that of `x` as `size(A)+size(y)+1`.

If you use the ideas from the finger search tree then you will also be able to iterate through the whole array in `O(n)`, iterate through a sequence of length `k` in `O(k)`, and skip forward or back from `A[i]` to `A[i+k]` or `A[i-k]` in `O(log k)`.

Answer (score -1):

B-tree is a good choice for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree